# Acumatica how to make a Custom Branch field not mandatory or be able to select branch from a lookup

Tags: acumatica

I'm facing the following issue:
I have created a user field "UsrBranch".

Using the Branch lookup from the SO Financial Settings, I'm able to select and save into my new "UsrBranch" field, but it makes the field mandatory, even when I set the field as "Required = false".
Example 1:

```
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Branch")]
    [Branch(typeof(Coalesce<Search<Location.cBranchID,
            Where<Location.bAccountID, Equal<Current<SOOrder.customerID>>,
                  And<Location.locationID, Equal<Current<SOOrder.customerLocationID>>>>>,
    Search<Branch.branchID, Where<Branch.branchID, 
                            Equal<Current<AccessInfo.branchID>>>>>), Required = false)]
    public virtual Int32? UsrBranch { get; set; }
    public abstract class usrBranch : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<usrBranch> { }
```

If I change the lookup to a PXSelector it displays the Branches, but I'm not able to select any. 
Example 2:

```
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Branch")]
    [PXSelector(typeof(Branch.branchID),
             SubstituteKey = typeof(Branch.branchCD))]
    public virtual Int32? UsrBranch { get; set; }
    public abstract class usrBranch : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<usrBranch> { }
```

Any Help will be gratefully appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Required" Property controls whether or not the star will show up on the field in the UI. The "PersistingCheck" property on the PXDefaultAttribute controls whether or not a value is mandatory.

The constructor of the BranchAttribute adds a PXDefaultAttribute to the field, and the default value for the "PersistingCheck" property is PXPersistingCheck.Null. This disallows the field from being null when saved. Since BranchAttribute derives from the AcctSubAttribute/PXAggregateAttribute you can set the "PersistingCheck" property on the BranchAttribute and it will set the "PersistingCheck" property on the added PXDefaultAttribute. To make it so the field can be null, set the "PersistingCheck" property to PXPersistingCheck.Nothing on the BranchAttribute:

```
[Branch(typeof(Coalesce<
                        Search<Location.cBranchID,
                                                  Where<Location.bAccountID, Equal<Current<SOOrder.customerID>>,
                                                      And<Location.locationID, Equal<Current<SOOrder.customerLocationID>>>>>,
                        Search<Branch.branchID, 
                                               Where<Branch.branchID, Equal<Current<AccessInfo.branchID>>>>>), PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Nothing)]
public virtual int? UsrBranch { get; set; }
```

Additionally, there is a PXUIFieldAttribute on the BranchAttribute so adding another one onto the field is redundant.